# How to install Vscode on Raspberry Pi Desktop (Live USB)

Tags: raspbian, live-usb

Whenever I try to install vscode on Raspberry Pi Desktop (Live USB), it asks me to type "Yes, do as I say!" And after that my Linux becomes dysfunctional. I have reinstalled Linux several times and tried installing vscode over and over and same thing happens.

One of the links I followed are: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=191342

I know the above link is for raspbian stretch and not for Desktop but there isn't any guide available to install vscode on Raspberry Pi Desktop.  I installed vscode using the same link on my Raspberry pi model B and it worked fine. I guess the reason why my Linux have been going dysfunctional is because my Linux is amd64 while this image is for armhf.

I also tried installing graphically from official website: https://code.visualstudio.com/download and downloaded .deb file, but it doesn't install and give error. (I don't remember what error)

Is there any way to install vscode on my live CD?